# Compute the infinite sum $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}k^2(\frac{1}{2})^{k-1}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

> I would like to compute the infinite sum $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}k^2\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{k-1}$$

How is that possible?

I tried to use the derivative method and got stuck here:

$$
 \frac{d^2}{d^2x}\frac{1}{1-x}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(k^2-k)x^{k-2}
$$

How can I continue from here? What manipulations am I allowed to do to reach the exact form?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have

$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(x \frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right) \right) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}k^2x^{k-1}$$

It follows:
$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(x \frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right) \right) = \frac{1+x}{(1-x)^3}\stackrel{x=\frac{1}{2}}{\Rightarrow}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}k^2(\frac{1}{2})^{k-1} = 12$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Multiply the whole thing by $x$ before you differentiate the second time.

Comment: Can I simply multiply both sides by x?

Comment: @superuser123 Sure. If $\frac{d}{dx}\frac{1}{1-x}$ is the same as $\sum_{k = 1}^\infty kx^{k-1}$, then $x\cdot \frac{d}{dx}\frac{1}{1-x}$ must be the same as $x\cdot \sum_{k = 1}^\infty kx^{k-1}$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider 
$$S=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}k^2 x^{k-1}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}[k(k-1)+k]x^{k-1}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}k(k-1)x^{k-1}+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}kx^{k-1}$$ that is to say
$$S=x\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}k(k-1)x^{k-2}+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}kx^{k-1}$$ or
$$S=x \left(\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}x^{k} \right)''+ \left(\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}x^{k} \right)'$$